# Referencing an input for form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm making a log-in username and password form. I'm wondering how to reference the two inputs separately to add and remove classes when they're hovered over. So for example, when you hover over the username box the color changes from red to a slightly lighter red. The basic code would be:

```
$('input').hover( function(){ 
    $(this).addClass('highlight'); 
}, function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass('highlight'); 
});
```

But how would I reference the two input's names "username" and "password" so that when each individual input box is hovered over it changes color?

Comment: You have already used `$(this)` to get current reference. So this should work.

Comment: Just use the `:hover` pseudo-class, and use an attribute selector and reference the `type` attribute

Comment: Do you want to highlight both inputs in the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'this' object is the current element that hovering over. http://jsfiddle.net/7BLLR/
It was a problem with my syntax. Just simple misspelling.

```
$('input').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your approach, `$('input')` will consider all input elements in the form.
But as you want only two input elements, you can use following :

```
$('input').hover( function(){ 
    if($(this).attr('name') == 'username' || $(this).attr('name') == 'password')){
          $(this).addClass('highlight'); 
    }
}, function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass('highlight'); 
});
```

Comment: `this.name` is hugely more efficient than `$(this).attr('name')`.